# Cardinality of $\omega^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know $ \omega ^ 2  $ is countable, but I'm unable to find a bijection from $ \omega * \omega  \rightarrow \omega $

This should be simple, but I'm very stuck.

Comment: Hint: lay out $\omega^2$ in a quarter-infinite grid, as the set of points $\langle x,y\rangle$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$.  Can you see how to enumerate all the points in this grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This picture shows one way:

[image]

If you have to describe this bijection $\varphi:\omega\times\omega\to\omega$ more formally, it’s worth spending some time trying to work out a formula for $\varphi(a,b)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$; all you need is a little ingenuity and the familiar formula for the sum of the first $n$ positive integers, $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac12n(n+1)$. If you get stuck, you’ll find much help in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Answer (score 1):

think about what it actually is on the inside:

$$\begin{array}?
\omega^2 = &\{&
0,1,2,3,\ldots, \\
&& \omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,\ldots, \\
&& 2\omega,2\omega+1,2\omega+2,2\omega+3,\ldots,\\
&& 3\omega,3\omega+1,3\omega+2,3\omega+3,\ldots, \\
&& \vdots \\ &\}& \end{array}$$

now can easily see why it is in bijection with $\mathbb N^2$ and hence $\mathbb N$ hence countable.